# Matlab builder ja

Tags: java, android, matlab

I want to use" Matlab builder ja" to make java package and use it in my android application, I have a problem with the source code of that package I did not found the source file please help.
the way that I followed:
1- I wrote in commend line "compiler library "
2-java package
3-run installer
**where can I found the source code**?
[this is my class that I make it in Matlab and all the function I need is inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJhmk.jpg)
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucql3.jpg)

Comment: Why do you expect to get source code? I suggest you read the documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/package-integration.html

Answer (score 3):

The Matlab Builder JA was renamed. Multiple similar products are now called "Matlab Compiler SDK". To get the names right:

- [Matlab Compiler](https://de.mathworks.com/help/compiler/index.html) Build standalone executables and web apps from MATLAB programs
- [Matlab Compiler SDK](https://de.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/index.html) MATLAB® Compiler SDK™ extends the functionality of MATLAB Compiler™ to let you build C/C++ shared libraries, Microsoft® .NET assemblies, and Java® classes from MATLAB programs.
- [Matlab Coder](https://de.mathworks.com/help/coder/index.html) Generate C and C++ code from MATLAB code

The MATLAB Compiler SDK is not suitable for your use-case. It generates a java library which requires the MATLAB Compiler Runtime to run. This is not specific to jar librarys, any code deployed with the MATLAB Compiler or MATLAB Compiler SDK requires the MATLAB Compiler Runtime to run. There is not MCR for android, which means you can ignore the Matlab Compiler and Matlab Compiler SDK.

To bring your MATLAB code onto an android device, your primary option is to generate C++ code using the MATLAB Coder, then compile this for your target. Please be aware that the MATLAB Coder can not generate code for arbitrary m code, there are some notable limitations.

[Matlab Compiler (SDK) and Matlab Coder are compared here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/223937-should-i-use-matlab-compiler-sdk-or-matlab-coder-to-integrate-my-matlab-applications-with-c-c), the focus is integration in C/C++, but still many important facts are collected there. (example: "Does it generate readable source code?"

Comment: thanks a lot but please can you explain more to me, I did not get the idea very well, or if you have a link for your idea write it, please.

Comment: I updated my question including links and additional information.

Comment: thank you a lot, I'm a beginner in android and my project needs to read the .wave file and detect the envelope and many things to detect the breathing rate so I tried a lot of methods a lot of ways and I did not get any result in java, So I want to make my code in Matlab and execute it in android(java). dose this way that you mentioned above help me with this? and if you have any ideas about what I want to do please help me. thank you very much .

Comment: That is too broad of a question to answer (without looking at your projects for a few hours which is time I will not invest). Have you checked the documented language limitations? If the coder can't generate code for the most important functions you are using, the approach is not useful.